# Cross-Class PDO Not Performing

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am re-working all of my mysql_* and mysqli connections to use PDO but I can't seem to even get the basics right.  I have two files: one that creates the connection and returns it and one that utilizes the connection for whatever purpose I deem necessary.  For some reason however, I cannot get the connection to return properly to be utilized.  If I run any PDO function (query, prepare, etc..), I get a server response of 500 with no error messages.  I do know however, that if I create the connection and query all in the same function, everything is hunky-dory. I am assuming is it something simple, so maybe fresh eyes can help me out.

**db_connect.php (to form the connection):**

```
class db_connect {

    function __construct() {}       
    function __destruct() {}

    public function connect() {
        require_once 'db_info.php';
        try{
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $dbh;
    }

    public function close() {
        $dbh = null;
    }
}
```

**operations.php (utilizes connection):**

```
class operations {

    private $dbh;       

    function __construct() {
        require_once 'db_connect.php';
        $this->dbh = new db_connect();
        $this->dbh->connect();
    }

    function runQuery() {
        // causes 500 error, no logs:
        $stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
    }
}
```

I did search around for some answers but none of the solutions I found worked for me.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Shouldn't `$dbh->query` be `$this->dbh->query` ? So that it refers to the object you created within the operations class. Also on your `db_connect` class the `close` function wouldn't do anything..

Comment: @dakdad I tried it, still nothing. I am really just using trial and error and this point. The problem is, I have not error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are effectively throwing away your PDO object.  When you call:

```
$this->dbh = new db_connect();
// $this->dbh is a db_connect

$this->dbh->connect();
// returns a PDO, which you don't save anywhere
```

Then later you try to do this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
// $dbh doesn't even exist
// You meant $this->dbh, but that won't work either
// $this->dbh is a db_connect object, which does not implement the query() method
```

I think what you meant to do was save the PDO object as part of db_connect, and then use it for queries:

```
class db_connect {

    public $connection;

    function __construct() {}       
    function __destruct() {}

    public function connect() {
        require_once 'db_info.php';
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        $this->connection = $dbh;
        return $dbh;
    }

    public function close() {
        $this->connection = null;
    }
}

class operations {

    private $dbh;       

    function __construct() {
        require_once 'db_connect.php';
        $this->dbh = new db_connect();
        $this->dbh->connect();
    }

    function runQuery() {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->connection->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
    }
}
```

Finally, if you're just using the db_connect class to generate a PDO connection, then you should turn connect() into a static method and just save the PDO object (as @dakdad mentioned).  Here, I have also moved your require_once to a more reasonable location:

```
---------- db_connect.php ----------

require_once "db_info.php";

class db_connect {
    public static function connect() {
        $dbh = null;
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_DATABASE, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection Failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
        return $dbh;
    }
}

---------- operations.php ----------

require_once "db_connect.php"

class operations {

    private $dbh;       

    function __construct() {
        $this->dbh = db_connect::connect();
    }

    function runQuery() {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM words limit 2");
        print_r( $stmt->fetchAll() ) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: That would explain my problem, but I was under the assumption that `$this->dbh->connection()` ran the connection function, returned the connection, and saved it to $dbh.  That is how I did it for `mysql_*` at least.  Can you please edit your answer to show how I "save" (as you put it) my PDO connection?

Comment: Thank you for extending your answer as you did, but it seems to be acting exactly as before with your code.

Comment: Fixed a bug in runQuery().  It should have referenced `$this->dbh` instead of `$dbh`.  Also, you should really think about moving your `require_once` statements to a place outside of your class definitions.  The usual place to put them is near the top of the PHP file.

Comment: Your answer helped the most, but @dakdad helped out with simplifying things.  Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Your `operations` class should store the PDO object, not the `db_connect` class.

```
class operations {

    private $dbh;       

    function __construct() {
        require_once 'db_connect.php';
        $db = new db_connect();
        $this->dbh = $db->connect();
    }

    function runQuery() {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->query("SELECT * FROM myTable");
    }
}
```

Similar to the answer from @slashingweapon just another way.